# Nginx Rewrite - How to redirect url for certain file type?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, cdn

My current bargain CDN has very poor performance on video caching. What's worse, I don't have any access to its setting.

So I am wondering is it possible to rewrite the url for certain file type to my server's IP address instead the CDN server?

should be something like this in Apache:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154666/apache-mod-rewrite-redirect-file-type-to-another-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your nginx config file somethink like:

```
location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
    rewrite ^(.*) http://someserver.com/$1 last;
}
```

You can see examples of `nginx` configuration of rewriting for example [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite) and some examples of location directive [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Comment: Thanks, I also found this guide comes in handy, http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/277439/How-to-convert-Apache-rewrites-for-nginx

Comment: It works! Now my video are redirected to my vps rather than via CDN. Somehow "Localhost" didn't work as url in this case, so I used the static IP instead.